# iOS UIKit - How to create a modify a custom UIView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uikit

I'm trying to create a custom UIView (`CardView`) and display it in a UITableView

```
class CardView: UIView {

    public var cardTitle = UILabel()
    public var cardValue = UILabel()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
    
        self.addSubview(cardTitle)
        self.addSubview(cardValue)
    
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        
        cardTitle.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: self.width, height: 25)
        cardValue.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: cardTitle.bottom + 1, width: self.width, height: 25)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The TableView looks like this:

```
class StatsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let identifier = "StatsID"

    private var cellTitleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        return label
    }()

    private var homeView: CardView = {
        let card = CardView()
        card.cardTitle.text = "Home"
        return card
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSubview()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        cellTitleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: contentView.width - 20, height: 20)
        homeView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: cellTitleLabel.bottom + 10, width: (contentView.width - 40) / 3, height: contentView.height - 25)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func addSubview() {
        contentView.addSubview(cellTitleLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(homeView)
    }

    func configure(with viewModel: StatsTableviewViewModel) {
        cellTitleLabel.text = viewModel.cellTitle
        homeView.cardValue.text = viewModel.homeValue
    }

}
```

On my `cellForRowAt` im tryin to configuring the cell like this:

```
extension WelcomeViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        viewmodels.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StatsTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? StatsTableViewCell else {
            fatalError()
        }
        print(viewmodels)
        cell.configure(with: viewmodels[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the `StatsViewController` it shows the `homeView` background and the `cellTitleLabel` but is not showing the `cardTitle` and `cardValue`

[Screenshot of the `StatsTableView`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQNGE.png)

I'm using an extension to access easier to width and height. That's why you're not seeing `.frame.size.height`

Comment: I see that you assign the width of the frames of `cardTitle` and `cardValue` as `self.width` during the initialisation of `CardView`, which at that point of time is 0 as you only assign the frame of your `CardView` after.